# Link to old Google Contact Manager

Tags: google-contacts

Is there a link by which I can open the old Google Contact Manager (the one with 3 columns layout)? It allowed instant search and the ability to view contact details on the same page.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the bottom of the screen is a link to "older version", which points to https://www.google.com/contacts_v1

So, the old version is still around, at least for a little while.

I would expect that there may be some incompatibilities with the new contact manager (some fields not supported for instance; Google+ Circles are definitely not there) and that they may finally kill it altogether. (They've done similar things with other products.)

---

2013-12-02: As predicted, the original version of Google Contacts is no longer available. (I don't know exactly when they took it away.)